# Abort trap 6 for working c program on a Mac

Tags: c, macos, clang, abort

So I wrote this program (Sourcecode: http://pastebin.com/kb3QedMw) that is basically a state machine (implemented in c) that reads a logfile and then calculates some averages. It's running smoothly and the output is correct as far as I can tell. But, if compiled on a Mac using clang 3.3, I get a message "Abort Trap 6" at the very end of the program (just before the return 0 or after it, as far as I can tell). On a linux machine with clang 3.4, everything seems fine.
Is this just some Mac weirdness again? I read here ([GNU Make "Abort trap: 6" after gcc call however call is valid when executed alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012950/gnu-make-abort-trap-6-after-gcc-call-however-call-is-valid-when-executed-alon)) that it indicates a SIGABRT signal, but I can't imagine where it should be coming from.
Any ideas what the cause is? I'm afraid of a bug I have not found yet that may be ruining my results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GNU Make "Abort trap: 6" after gcc call however call is valid when executed alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012950/gnu-make-abort-trap-6-after-gcc-call-however-call-is-valid-when-executed-alon)

Comment: Run in a debugger, it will stop at the "trap", and you should be able to see the function call stack to see how it arrived at the trap. You will then be able to walk up the stack to your function and debug your code, if any.

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but may save you from some headaches: Embrace expressions in macros: `#define NUM_BINS (HEIGHT/BINHEIGHT)`. And variables with file scope and static variables are automatically initialized to 0/0.0/0-pointer (It's not a mistake to do so explicitly, of course, but you sometimes initialize explicitly, sometimes not).

Comment: @mafso Thanks for the tips. I thought %lf was for double. Wikipedia says so, as do other sites.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I have to wait for my system administrator to come back from his holiday because the configuration of our systems is crap and I need the admin password to run a debugger :-(

Comment: Can you post a small chunk of logfile that causes the crash (a chunk large enough to cause the crash) - probably on Pastebin.